# How to regroup JSON to match data types in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, data-conversion

The goal here is to group JSON data by date and convert it into object in Flutter.

API of service I'm using returns JSON in this format:

```
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Article Name",
            "created_at": "2020-01-10T00:33:09.000000Z",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Article Name",
            "created_at": "2020-01-10T00:33:09.000000Z",
        },
```

I need to convert it to following format:

```
  Map<String, List<Article>> ArticleHistory = {
    '04.08.2020': [
      Article(id: 16, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 15, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 14, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 13, name: 'Article Name'),
    ],
    '03.08.2020': [
      Article(id: 12, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 11, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 10, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 9, name: 'Article Name'),
    ],
    '02.08.2020': [
      Article(id: 8, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 7, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 6, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 5, name: 'Article Name'),
    ],
    '01.08.2020': [
      Article(id: 4, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 3, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 2, name: 'Article Name'),
      Article(id: 1, name: 'Article Name'),
    ],
  };
```

How that can be achieved?

Comment: Are you sure you want map key be String, not DateTime?

Comment: Yeah, sure thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let you have data in the following format:

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> articlesListJson = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Article 1",
    "created_at": "2020-08-01T00:30:00.000000Z",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Article 2",
    "created_at": "2020-08-01T00:45:00.000000Z",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Article 3",
    "created_at": "2020-08-02T00:00:00.000000Z",
  },
];
```

*(If you have a json string instead, use [jsonDecode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) function to parse it to Dart's `List` of `Map`'s).*

As you want to store dates as dd.mm.yyyy String, write a helper function for converting `2020-08-01T00:30:00.000000Z` to `01.08.2020`:

```dart
String extractDateString(String dateTimeString) {
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
  String day = dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  String month = dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  String year = dateTime.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0');
  return '$day.$month.$year';
}
```

Then you'll be able to group the list by date:

```dart
Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> articleGroupsJson = groupBy(
  articlesListJson,
  (a) => extractDateString(a['created_at']),
);
// {'01.08.2020': [{...}, {...}], '02.08.2020': [{...}]}
```

*`groupBy` is from [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package. Depend on it or just copy-paste [function source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html).*

Now parse each `Map<String, dynamic>` to `Article` class:

```dart
class Article {
  int id;
  String name;
  
  Article({this.id, this.name});
}
```

in a standard way:

```dart
Article parseArticle(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return Article(
    id: map['id'],
    name: map['name'],
  );
}
```

Because the data is already groupped, instead of simply mapping the list you'll need to map groups, and for each group map its value (which is list)

```dart
Map<String, List<Article>> articleGroups = articleGroupsJson.map(
  (date, list) => MapEntry(
    date,
    list.map(parseArticle).toList(),
  ),
);
```

Now `articleGroups` has the structure you want

Comment: Note that if you use String to represent date in Map keys, the behavior might depend on device's time zone

Comment: Also instead of manual DateTime formatting, [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package can be used